# Python with selenium: unable to locate element which really exist

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying fill input:

```
<input id="PASSFIELD1" class="logField" type="password" onkeyup="next(this, event);" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" name="PASSFIELD1"></input>
```

To do this, I have to find this element.

I tried below things:

1. `pass1=driver.find_element_by_name("PASSFIELD1")`
2. `pass1=driver.find_element_by_id("PASSFIELD1")`
3. `pass1= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]")`  (path from firebug)
4. Even wait 100 seconds for it

`self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]")))
self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]"))`

I always get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to locate element: (...)

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the element inside an iframe ?

Comment: Besides what @alecxe said, is there also a "nearby" username field that _are_ to find and interact with?

Comment: @Amey, alecxe: well, page starts with:                          <html>
<head>
<frameset border="1" rows="100%,*">
<frame frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize" name="main"                 then i guess it is. Do you know how to handle with that?

Comment: @SiKing: No, it is on the previous page.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that your `input` tag is inside an `iframe`, you need to [switch to](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) it first:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="main"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
pass1 = driver.find_element_by_id("PASSFIELD1")
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you. I have to say that you previous question was good and i found it by myself on the website: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames                                                          Again, big thanks to you all.

Answer (score 7):

Add some delay to the driver so that elements will load.

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
department_element = driver.find_elements_by_id("__id_name__")
```

or else you can use the following code so that loop runs until the element render

```
while len(driver.find_elements_by_id("__id_name__")) == 0:
    pass
department_element = driver.find_elements_by_id("__id_name__")
```