# Python with Selenium: Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to fill a text box but I am getting unable to locate element.

I have tried finding the element

- by class
- by name
- Added 10 secs wait

But I am still getting the same error.

**Here is HTML**

```
    <div class="innerWrap">
    <textarea aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="typeahead_list_u_0_j"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label=
    "Write a birthday wish on his Timeline..." class=
    "enter_submit uiTextareaNoResize uiTextareaAutogrow uiStreamInlineTextarea inlineReplyTextArea mentionsTextarea textInput"
    cols="48" id="u_0_k" name="message_text" placeholder=
    "Write a birthday wish on his Timeline..." role="textbox" title=
    "Write a birthday wish on his Timeline..."></textarea>
</div>
```

**My Code:**

```
textbox =  driver.find_element_by_name('message_text')
textbox.send_keys('Happy Birthday! ')
```

The web page I am working on is [Facebook Birthdays page](https://www.facebook.com/birthdays/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was finally able to find the element and fix the above error by looking at the page source.

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Page source showed the name of element was `message` and not `message_text`. However inspect element in browser still shows `message_text`.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered before but the doc links that the answer points to is outdated, so here is the new updated ["switch to"/switch commands selenium docs](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/) link

You need to use this command to switch your driver so that it runs in the correct window/frame/ etc.

Check which windows are open by running: first run `driver.getWindowHandles();` to return a set of all windows

Then use `driver.switchTo().window(handle);} #if switching to another window`

or     `driver.switchTo().frame("yourframename");} #if switching to a frame`

or     `driver.switchTo().alert(); #if switching to a popup`

Hope this helps

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369249/python-with-selenium-unable-to-locate-element-which-really-exist)

Comment: I did eventually succeeded in finding the element but through a different approach. I tried changing window and frame but that didn't helped as I was already in the same window and there is no iframe in the code. So I downloaded the page source through `driver.page_source` and the name of element I wanted to target in the downloaded source is actually "message" and not "message_text". However when I check the name of this element in browser through inspect element it still shows "message_text". I am not sure why there is difference of element name.

Comment: @AbdulMoizFarooq that's an interesting discovery. You should post it as an answer to help other people. Thanks for the update.