# Appium - find element by xpath not working

Tags: appium, python-appium

[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP3qx.png)Trying to click on an element XPath not working. I have used several other XPath in my application. All other working expect this!

**driver.find_element_by_xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.RelativeLayout/androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BioJo.png)/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BioJo.png)").click()**

Comment: Does this element load along with the activity or is there any delay in loading?

Comment: Loads along with the activity. As soon as I click my element will get load. I tried this same code around 50 times 2-3 it worked also.

Comment: Did you try adding some delay before this line of code?
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58328089/12096447

Comment: I tried it didn't work -:

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "").click()

Comment: print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(""))  
print(len(driver.find_element_by_xpath("")))

Could you share the output of these lines?

Comment: print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("")) -: <appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="8fb39e7c-8319-4f51-b513-b38d9c3795a6", element="c04a61df-88ce-479b-afab-70a8b7f9ec1f")>

print(len(driver.find_element_by_xpath(""))) -: TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @VishalParashar
Can you share outputs of these also?
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("")) 
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("")))
element --> elements